# Change directory to location of executable

Tags: linux

How do I change directory to location of executable from a Linux terminal?

I tried, e.g., `cd $(which ruby)/..` but that doesn't work.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: GNU bash version 3.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
cd $(dirname `which ruby`)
```

Answer (score 0):

`which` command tells you not only directory name but also filename, so you have to get rid of the filename using some utility. I used simple `sed` for this to remove everything after last slash including.

This works in bash:

```
cd `which ls | sed -r 's#/[^/]+$##'`
```